# Upload video from cordova app to vimeo

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest, vimeo-api

I've encountered a problem while uploading a video from my ionic cordova app to my Vimeo account.

first, i've tried the upload-cordova.js (on git) method:

```
var uploader = new MediaUploader({
           file: files[0],
           isCordovaApp: true,
           contentType: 'video/mp4',
           token: myToken,
           onComplete: function(data) { console.log(data); },
           onError: function(data) { console.log(data); }
         });
uploader.upload();
```

I got the following error on vimeo:
"There was a problem with the file you tried to upload. Either it’s not a video file or it uses a codec we don’t accept"

next, i've tried using cordovas FileTransferObject:

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
fileTransfer.upload(video.fullPath, response.upload_link_secure, {
                headers: [                   
                  {"Content-Type": "video/mp4"},
                  {'Content-Length': video.size}
                ],
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                fileKey: "MyFile",
                fileName: videoNewName
              }, true).then(c => {
                //delete request
              });
```

With this one my video is stuck on "Your video is uploading" on vimeo...

I've tried different Content-types/MimeTypes, PUT/POST, some of the combinations didn't upload the file. this is the closest i've got.

Has anyone came across these problems, or has another way of uploading a video
between those two platforms?...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upload with fileTransfer.
turns out the filekey has to be "file_data".

its mentioned in the api for simple post, but not for the streaming option...